# How to remove UnicodeDecodeError when build azure sphere app with VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, python-unicode, azure-sphere

When I try to build a sample app with VS Code, it's failed because of UnicodeDecodeError.

Below is VS code Output tab snapshot.

[image]

I think the problem is displaying results with azsphere CLI, by SDK.(maybe python based).

Because when using the command `azsphere image-package show --image-package <path>`, got the same error.
In the command result, there is Korean character to display 'morning' or 'afternoon'.

I know that the Unicode character is not supported with Azure Sphere CLI.
but I didn't use the Unicode characters in Product or Device group.

When using Visual Studio, there are broken characters but the result not failed.

[image]

How can I remove VS code build error?
I want to use VS code as Azure Sphere development environment.